# Can a broken power supply freeze Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, kernel, power-management

Several months ago my Ubuntu 10.04 started to freeze some minutes after booting. I didn't reboot, just get stuck (mouse, keyboard, etc.)

One day it didn't boot at all - ut was dead. I tested the power supply and it was broken, so I changed it (for a more powerful one) and both problems are gone. Since 3 weeks, the PC is working fine. It didn't freezes anymore.

- Can the power supply affect the OS in this way? May it because of a leak of current?

Answer (score 2):

With an hardware failure, the software can reach some random behavior.

I would suggest to check your system logs files (using `gnome-system-log` application for example) and look at if some errors were reported when you observed the issue.

Comment: Hi Yanok, this never happened again since I changed the broken power supply,... so in some way, my problem is gone. However I wondered if this could be due to an insufficient power supply

Comment: Hi Luso. Great to know your problem is solve then :-)If you did not observe other errors in software logs, feel lucky that your issue was due to power supply failure.